# How do I display the minutes in two digits using c++ for my time program?

Tags: c++

Below is my program in c++. Please help. Thanks.

```
void Time::showTime()
{
    cout <<  "Your time in 24 hours military standard is " << hour << ":" << minute << endl;  
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw

Comment: And use time() and gmtime() by adding an #include <ctime>

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed for being "unclear."  There is nothing ambiguous at all about what's being asked here.

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << setw (2) << setfill ('0') << minute << "\n";
```

Note that:

1. You don't normally need to insert `endl`.  Just insert an `\n` instead -- `endl` also flushes the stream, which is typically not needed.
2. In order to use `setw` and `setfill` you need to `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: @Zaibis:  Uh, whoops.

Comment: @Zaibis thanks for the correction as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of task for which `strftime` was designed. It eliminates a fair amount of work with `setfill`, `setw`, etc.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

enum conv {UTC, LOCAL};

std::string fmt(char const *fmt, time_t p=time(NULL), conv c = LOCAL) {
    char buffer[512];

    struct tm n = c == LOCAL ? *localtime(&p) : *gmtime(&p);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fmt, &n);
    return std::string(buffer);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt("Your time in 24 hours military standard is %H:%M\n");
}
```

In theory, C++11 has added `<chrono>` and a `put_time` manipulator that lets you do this retrieval and formatting a little more cleanly, but support in real compilers is...spotty at best. Most seem to have the code to retrieve times, but the `put_time` manipulator is still missing in a fair number of popular implementations.